# Clone single site into a multisite setup

Tags: multisite, clone-site

Is there a way to clone a single website into a multisite setup, also having that new site as the main site IE www.mydomain.com

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to clone and locally run a network for testing](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/276467/how-to-clone-and-locally-run-a-network-for-testing)

Comment: Sites in a multisite don't have to follow the subdomain or subfolder rules, those are just convention. There's nothing stopping you changing the URL of a blog on a multisite to banana.com, even if your root site is mydomain.com, WP will happily serve custom domains without plugins or code adjustments

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this easily. Just install multisite and import on main site.

Process:
You have running mydomain.com. Now keep backup this website.

Now,
1. install website on multi-site
2. Import complete webiste on main domain mydomain.com
3. Set permalink as per your requirement on main site.
4. Add another site from network. Export theme setting and import setting on another site.

Best of Luck.